# Display images in a Spring boot Thymeleaf template for email

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My images are not rendering properly, please assist. Thank! My folder structure looks like the below attachment:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question may get a better response if you include the code as code rather than a screenshot (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551), add a screenshot of what's happening ("not rendering properly" is a bit vague), and explain what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: If you remove `th:src` tag, is the image be shown?

Comment: @codingmonster I removed the tage and it still does not work.

Comment: Then it's not a thymeleaf problem. It may related to your configuration or directory structure. Please let me know your config files and directory full tree.

Comment: @codingmonster How can I share my folder structure to you?

Comment: Express directory tree with characters like `|__` or screenshot, I don't need **full tree**, just  the `resources/../../`.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNQzW.png  please see the link.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
> called **/static** (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in
> the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

remove resource/static
like so:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/momentum-header.jpg}"/>
```

Also if you have Spring Security make sure to allow requests to your resources by overriding this method in your Security Configuration class (the one extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)